# Is it possible to use the Forena module in conjunction with the Flot module?

Tags: charts, forena

I need to plot based on some data that will be fetched from an external (non-drupal) database. I have found the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module, but in the part I do not like about the graph utility it uses by default.

Is it possible to use the [Flot](https://www.drupal.org/project/flot) module in conjunction with [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena)?

The Forena module says: "Virtually any JavaScript library may be used with Forena to produce amazing displays".

How is it implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to use the [Flot](https://www.drupal.org/project/flot) module in conjunction with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) module.

About "Virtually any JavaScript library may be used with Forena ...": have a look at the [feature request # 2364427](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364427), especially these comments in it:

- [Comment nr 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364427#comment-9363133), which is about a module for using Forena data with the [d3js library](http://d3js.org/).
- [Comment nr 15](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364427#comment-9384121), which is about a [related sandbox project](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/metzlerd/frx).
- [Comment nr 18](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364427#comment-9384397), about the [D3 strategy](https://www.drupal.org/node/2383509).

Another approach is to write your own "renderer", as a variation of the [FrxSVGGraph renderer](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/forena/tree/renderers/FrxSVGGraph.inc) (which extends [FrxRenderer](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/forena/tree/renderers/FrxRenderer.inc)), and which is how the current support for the [PHP SVGGraph library](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.setup#svggraph) is implemented.